# Remove duplicate line with timestamp from text file in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop a software tool which can store data into log file continuously. The data is repeated and I wanted to remove all duplicate lines and store into log file. I went through couple of forums and found solution/s but that's not the one I am looking for. Here is my situation:

FM Radio stations broadcast a standard message during commercial break let's say "Soft Rock KWAV 96.9FM"  for certain period of time and after few minutes they broadcast a song with title or artist name etc. I am able to store all the information into my log file with no duplicate lines. My problem is, when song is finished there is 10 min's commercial break again, at this point of time my current log file already contained the message ("Soft Rock KWAV 96.9 FM" ), so it's not allowing the second repeated message into the text file. If I run my software and look at the log file at the end of the day,  there will be only one commercial break, which is not correct.

Any suggestions/ideas would be much appreciated.

Input Data:

02/15/2013, 09:12, Soft

02/15/2013, 09:12, Soft

02/15/2013, 09:12, Soft

02/15/2013, 09:12, Soft

02/15/2013, 09:12, Soft

02/15/2013, 09:12, Soft

02/15/2013, 09:12, Rock

02/15/2013, 09:12, Rock

02/15/2013, 09:12, Rock

02/15/2013, 09:12, Rock

02/15/2013, 09:12, Rock

02/15/2013, 09:12, Rock

02/15/2013, 09:12, KWAV

02/15/2013, 09:12, KWAV

02/15/2013, 09:12, KWAV

02/15/2013, 09:12, KWAV

02/15/2013, 09:12, KWAV

02/15/2013, 09:12, KWAV

02/15/2013, 09:12, 96.9 FM

02/15/2013, 09:12, 96.9 FM

02/15/2013, 09:12, 96.9 FM

02/15/2013, 09:12, 96.9 FM

02/15/2013, 09:12, 96.9 FM

02/15/2013, 09:12, 96.9 FM

02/15/2013, 09:13, Soft

02/15/2013, 09:13, Soft

02/15/2013, 09:13, Soft

02/15/2013, 09:13, Soft

And then next song/title/artist name and so on...

Comment: What kind of code do you have currently.. can you show how you are currently reading the lines of data that you want to log..?

Comment: If you dont show us anything about your software we cant help, you could have a restriction in the code, or the database, we cant help you if you dont improve your question.

Comment: I'm confuzzled - are you trying to add the duplicates or to remove them? what does your actual log file and system look like?

Comment: I am storing raw data into temporary log file and read the file using "Streamreader" method and then remove the duplicate lines later storing the file into new text file. I wish I could add raw data file to this post. The data itself is repeating , I can't control the feed. Is the information helpful.

Comment: Rekha can't you think on your own?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezwyzy7b.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx

I would use a combination of these two posts.

```
// load a StreamReader to the old path
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(oldPath)) 
{
    // load a StreamWriter to the new path
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(newPath)) 
    {
        string lastLine = string.empty();
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine();

            // if the line's text is different from the previous, write it
            if (line != lastLine)
            {            
                sw.WriteLine(line);
                lastLine = line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that you only want to filter out consecutive lines and that you'll be running this periodically. disclaimer: I haven't actually run this code.

Comment: The logic is working but my problem is different. Please check my last post in this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/878a465c-8c08-4857-b1c0-adc0a0b5d5cc